# JMeter - How to pass data from the CSV Data Set Config to the ForEach Controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My .csv file contains only one column called **domain**
I have very simple script:

Thread Group
      CSV Data Set Config
      Debug Sampler - ${domain}
      ForEach Controller (in has input variable **domain** and output variable **out**)
            Debug Sampler - ${out}

 
It executes the first Debug Sampler but not the second one.
I assume that ForEach does not get the **domain** variable from the CSV Data Set Config.
Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the value of ${domain} in your script? How are you reading the csv file? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: please add View Results Tree and run the script, share the results of View Results Tree

Comment: I just uploaded two screenshots. The data file has two values: Google, Yahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the [For Each Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) in the wrong manner. basically, it expects the input as a list of values, which can be accessed using `domain_1`, `domain_2` etc where `domain` is the value defined in the `Input variable prefix` field. This controller is primarily used with the combination of [Reg Ex Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), which gives similar out (list of values) and accessing mechanism of them (using `domain_1`).

In your case, `domain_1` & `domain_2` are not defined, samplers inside won't be executed.

So, you must create/provide the input in the format `For Each Controller` expects Or use other controllers like [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) etc.

**Note:** In order to provide the list of values as `For Each Controller` expects from CSV file, you can define more columns as follows:

```
domain_1,domain_2,...domain_n
google,yahoo,...bing
```

so, you can define `Input variable prefix` as `domain`, and make `domain_1` & `domain_2` variables available to the `For Each Controller` (As defined in the column fields).